# Imported Project in Android Studio can't resolve ActivityRecognnitionClient

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I imported a project from Eclipse to Android Studio. It uses Activity Recognition and Location Services. Now, this Android Studio project can resolve :

1) **GooglePlayServicesClient**(com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient) and even

2) **DetectedActivity**(com.google.android.gms.location.DetectedActivity)

but **can't resolve** **ActivityRecognitionClient**(com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient).

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not including Google play services in your project structure properly. go to your project structure and Import the latest maven for google play services

Comment: I followed this - [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: I also followed the same link. Perhaps you should check your project Structure properly and if the same problem persists then try downloading the sample from developer.android.com and Import that project directly to android studio. There after you may change the code