# Why eclipse can not resolve com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient?

Tags: android, eclipse, import, activity-recognition

1. I want to use google ActivityRecognition service in my android application.
2. I've install google play services from SDK manager and add google_play_services_lib project to my project by import option and hitting "copy project to your workspace" checkbox.
3. I'v been wrote a code according to this link: [Android Activity Recognition not working with Nexus 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352134/android-activity-recognition-not-working-with-nexus-5)
4. My import list is as bellow:

   import android.app.PendingIntent;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.hardware.Sensor;
   import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
   import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
   import android.hardware.SensorManager;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
   import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
   import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
   import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient;

   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
5. My android project can resolve all import excepting com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient!!!!
6. I copied sample activityRecognition project from developer.android.com and open it from my eclipse but there is the same problem with ActivityRecognitionClient!!!
7. I found a similar problem here: [Imported Project in Android Studio can't resolve ActivityRecognnitionClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541048/imported-project-in-android-studio-cant-resolve-activityrecognnitionclient)
   but not helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've add the bellow 3 jar files into the libs directory of my project and the problem is solved!

- sdk/tools/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar
- sdk/tools/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar
- sdk/tools/lib/httpmime-4.1.jar